# Can I have an object return a default value if no methods are called?

Tags: java

As an example, I want to mimic the functionality of the String object:

```
String mystring = new String ( "Hi there." );
System.out.println(mystring); // prints "Hi there." without calling any methods on String
                              // (that is what I want with my object)
System.out.println(mystring.toUpperCase()); // prints "HI THERE."
```

Starting with this:

```
class MyObject
{
    private Int value ;

    public MyObject ( Int value )
    {
        this.value = value ;
    }
    public Int getValue ( )
    {
        return this.value ;
    }
    public Int multiplyBy ( Int multiplier )
    {
        return this.value * multiplier ;
    }
}
```

... How (or can I) do something like this:

```
MyObject myobject = new MyObject ( 6 ) ;
System.out.println( myobject ) ; // want to print myobject.value (6)
System.out.println( myobject.multiplyBy ( 2 ) ) ; // print 12
```

I'm quite new to Java and realize that I'm probably missing some fundamental concept, but any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
The responses about overriding the toString method were helpful, but it's not quite doing what I had in mind, here's a better example of what I want:

```
Double mydouble = new Double ( 20.1 ) ;
System.out.println ( mydouble + 10.1 ) ; // prints 30.2
```

How would I do this with my own object (assuming I want the default value to be a double)?

Thanks again.

Final Edit (hopefully):
Your answers were enough to lead me to learn more about Primitive Wrappers and Autounboxing. My understanding is that there's no way to do what I want (which at this point, I would describe as autounboxing my object as a double), or at least I'll save that for another question. Cheers.

Comment: A method is always called even if you are not aware that it has been. ;)

Comment: I guess my question then is what method is being called on mydouble when I print mydouble + 10.1 that allows it to evaluate as 30.2 (if I use toString on my object it says "operator + cannot be applied to MyObject,angle).

Comment: You cannot change operators in Java.

Comment: Can you explain how the Double object does this though? I can do System.out.println(mydouble+"hi") and it prints "20.1hi" or System.out.println(mydouble+0.1) and it prints "20.2". Once I get this concept I think I'll have a much better understanding of Java.

Comment: All the operators are simple numeric or boolean operators except one.  If you use `+` with a String it will append both arguments to a StringBuilder and toString the result. e.g. `10.1 + "," + 20.9` is the same as `new StringBuilder().append(10.1).append(",").append(20.9).toString();` append(double) calls Double.toString(double) to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it: all you need to do is overriding `toString`:

```
public String toString() {
    return ""+this.value;
}
```

This works because `println` calls `toString` on objects being printed.

Comment: That was an incredibly fast and easy answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I'm running into a problem with what I was doing: Can I have it return a different type similar to: Double mydouble = new Double(20.0); System.out.println(mydouble + 10.2); // prints 30.2

Comment: @Synexis Unfortunately, you cannot do it in Java, because it does not support operator overloading or conversion operators.

Answer (score 3):

override `toString()method` in your **MyObject class**.

```
private int value ;
public String toString() {
  return Integer.toString(this.value);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java will always execute the "inner" statements first. So say we have a Double:

`Double db = new Double(20.1);`

Then you want to do this:

`System.out.println(db + 10)`

Then the compiler will do this part first `db + 10` which with auto boxing/unboxing becomes `db.doubleValue() + 10` which is evaluated to `30.1`. Then the outter function (`System.out.println(x)`) is evaluated with `x=30`.

When you have the following code `System.out.println(db + "hi")` the compiler sees that your are adding something (`db`) to a string `"hi"` and therefore calls `.toString()` on `db`. and then adds that (the string) to "hi" which will give you the final string: `"20.1hi"`

Hopefully that helps you understand what going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it so that the instance method returns a new instance:

```
public MyObject multiplyBy(int multipler)
{
    return new MyObject(value * multipler);
}
```

(oh, and that will be `int`, not `Int`)

and implement .toString():

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return Integer.toString(value);
}
```